# Generated with Java JJWT signature fails at jwt.io debugger

Tags: java, jwt, json-web-token, jjwt

I am using the jjwt Java library for server side generation of jwt in on servlets, the code snipper below straight from the jjwt GitHub page https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt generates and prints out this token.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKb2UifQ.XIKER3owR8BS3Krhsksg9INh9VBSejdn_qN-ONtPans
```

```java
 String compactJws = Jwts.builder()
      .setSubject("Joe")
      .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secret")
      .compact();
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println(compactJws);
```

However, when I try to verify this token on jwt.io's debugger, it fails the signature check.
[Both checking and unchecking secret base64 encoded didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2FVC.png)

Am I using the library wrongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `secr` and check the base64 option :)

It is due to `.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secret")`. It is implemented by [DefaultJwtBuilder](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/impl/DefaultJwtBuilder.java%60) class

```
public JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String base64EncodedSecretKey)
```

This method assumes that you are providing a key in base64 and **`secret` is not base64**. When the method decodes from `base64` to `byte[]` the java converter used by *jjwt* provides a representation of the string `secr` which is different to the JavaScript decoder used at **jwt.io**

You can test yourself with

```
System.out.println(
                javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(
                        javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("secret")));
```